# Override a jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I have a "core" javascript with some jQuery functions I can't touch, and a "custom" javascript with scripts I write

I'd like to override some "core" functions with my "custom" ones. i.e. like this

```js
// Core script (app.js), I can't touch this
var App = function(){
    // function to override or to inherit
    var handleBootstrapConfirmation = function(){
        $('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
            btnOkClass: 'btn btn-sm btn-success',
            btnCancelClass: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger'
        })
    };
    return {
        init: function(){
            handleBootstrapConfirmation();
        }
    }
}();
$(document).ready(function() {
    App.init();
});

// Custom script (custom.js), I can touch this
var Custom = function(){
    // this should override the previous one
    var handleBootstrapConfirmation = function(){
        $('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
            title: 'Custom title'
            // other options here
        })
    };
    return {
        init: function(){
            handleBootstrapConfirmation();
        }
    }
}();
$(document).ready(function() {
    Custom.init();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mistic100-Bootstrap-Confirmation/2.4.0/bootstrap-confirmation.min.js"></script>
<p style="padding:120px 80px"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="confirmation">Delete?</a></p>
```

You see, the App `handleBootstrapConfirmation()` is executed but the Custom `handleBootstrapConfirmation()` is not: I have to comment the `App.init();` line to make it work

I know I can change things in Custom script (as `$('[data-toggle=confirm]')` instead of `$('[data-toggle=confirmation]')`) but I'd like to keep things consistent

Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Overriding and inheriting are completely contradictory concepts. Which one do you want?

Comment: Uhm... override is preferable (I meant 'inherit' in the sense of 'inherit options specified ins App function so that I shouldn't type them again in Custom script')